# If $5x+7y=-56$, then

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would appreciate some help in solving this. I don't understand how to do it because the second equation does not equal zero. It's just literally asking for what it equals.

If $5x+7y=-56$, then $\left(\dfrac53 x+\dfrac78 y\right)+\left(\dfrac58 x+\dfrac73 y\right)=$

If someone could edit and fix formatting that would be helpful. I'm not sure how to format math equations.

Comment: Have you tried finding a common denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\left(\frac53 x+\frac78 y\right)+\left(\frac58 x+\frac73 y\right)&=\frac{40x+21y}{24}+\frac{15x+56y}{24}\\&=
\frac{55x+77y}{24}\\&=
\frac{11(5x+7y)}{24}\\&=
\frac{11(-56)}{24}\\&=
\frac{11(-7)}{3}\\&=
-\frac{77}{3}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. I have accepted yours because I like how you factored out 11. :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{rl}\left(\frac53 x+\frac78 y\right)+\left(\frac58 x+\frac73 y\right)&=\left(\frac53 x+\frac73 y\right)+\left(\frac58 x+\frac78 y\right)\\&=\left(\frac{5x+7y}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{5x+7y}{8}\right)\\&=\frac{-56}{3}+\frac{-56}{8}\end{array}$$

... and you should be able to tidy up the last expression whichever way you are normally asked to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.